# Change session ID and keep data?

Tags: php, session

When a user logs in on our website, I want to change the session ID but keep whatever data is in the session. I want to do this for two reasons:

1. To prevent a user account to be used at multiple places simultaneously (because if two people are using the same account, the actions of one will undermine the actions of the other).
2. To let the user continue what he/she was doing on another computer (e.g moving from home computer to work).

These might seem contradictory, but really aren't if you think it through.

The problem is as follows; to get to the data that is currently in the session, I have to call `session_start()`. This means I cannot call `session_id()` afterwards to set a new session ID.  Any ideas how to transfer the session data and change the session ID.

*Update*: I need to be able to choose the session ID myself. `session_regenerate_id()` therefore won't work.

Comment: `session_regenerate_id()` is the solution as cletus has noted.

Comment: Just how will you retrieve the session connected with a browser at work for a new session created from a browser at home?

Comment: @Don: By setting the session ID to be regeneratable for that user. 
@pygorex1: `session_regenerate_id()` won't work, I need to pick the new session ID myself.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You might be able to use [`session_regenerate_id()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-regenerate-id.php):

> ```
> <?php
> session_start();
>
> $old_sessionid = session_id();
>
> session_regenerate_id();
>
> $new_sessionid = session_id();
>
> echo "Old Session: $old_sessionid<br />";
> echo "New Session: $new_sessionid<br />";
>
> print_r($_SESSION);
> ?>
> ```

or even a cruder approach **might** work:

```
// save the session
session_start();
$session = array();
foreach ($_SESSION as $k => $v) {
  $session[$k] = $v;
}
session_commit();

// create new session and copy variables
session_id("new session id");
session_start();
foreach ($session as $k => $v) {
  $_SESSION[$k] = $v;
}
```

Comment: First approach should be enough.

Comment: Is it wrong to use `$session = $_SESSION` and then (after setting new session id) `$_SESSION = $session`?

Comment: @TheFrost: PHP does not copy by value but by reference, so that would just give `$_SESSION` a different identifier to use; modifications to both would be present with both vars.

Comment: @Smar PHP will copy simple variables by value. Objects are copied by reference, this is why `clone` is required to actually make a copy of an object. Try this: `$a = 0;$b = $a;$a++;echo 'a: ' . $a . ', b: ' . $b;`.

Comment: @TheFrost: $_SESSION is an array, and arrays *are* copied by value, but the values inside the array aren’t. Since array isn’t an object, clone doesn’t do anything to it...

Answer (score 4):

Use this. Put it to a function:

```
function update_session($newsessid = '') {

    // Backup the current session
        $session_backup = $_SESSION;

    // Set current session to expire in 1 minute            
        $_SESSION['OBSOLETE'] = true;
        $_SESSION['EXPIRES'] = time() + 60;

    // Close the current session
        session_write_close();

    // Set a new session id and start the session           
        $newSession = session_id($newsessid);
        session_start();

    // Restore the previous session backup
        $_SESSION = $session_backup;

    // Clean up
        unset($session_backup);                 
        unset($_SESSION['OBSOLETE']);
        unset($_SESSION['EXPIRES']);    
}
```

You would then call it when required:

```
update_session($customid);
```

Answer (score -1):

Or, you may just be able to use something like this:

```
$path=session_save_path();
$whatever_session_id;
```

pass these variables to the next page:

```
session_id()=$whatever_session_id;
session_save_path()=$path;
```

You'd be setting the path of the new session id to the old session data....
I don't know if this is really what you'd want, be here it is.